# Extracting altitude information from GeoTIFF data file in Python

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff

I have downloaded a GeoTIFF data file, and I want to get the altitude information given the coordinates in degrees. So I want something like

```
get_elevation(lat, long):
    ...
```

and then when you do

```
get_elevation(45.833333, 6.867222)
```

it returns something like `4807`. That is the altitude of the location of Mont Blanc.

How can I extract this information from a GeoTIFF data file in Python?

I tried an answer given [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24956653/read-elevation-using-gdal-python-from-geotiff):

```
import rasterio

# Which band are you interested. 
# 1 if there is only one band
band_of_interest = 1

# Row and Columns of the raster you want to know
# the value
row_of_interest = 30
column_of_interest = 50

# open the raster and close it automatically
# See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369526
with rasterio.open("SRTM/srtm_37_09.tif") as dataset:
    band = dataset.read(band_of_interest)
    value_of_interest = band(row_of_interest, column_of_interest)
    print(value_of_interest)
```

which just gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tester.py", line 18, in <module>
    value_of_interest = band(row_of_interest, column_of_interest)
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

How to do it?

How can I ***easily*** get the elevation data and its associated coordinates?

Comment: What in the many existing answers to this did not work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60127026/python-how-do-i-get-the-pixel-values-from-an-geotiff-map-by-coordinate , https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/299787/finding-pixel-location-in-raster-using-coordinates , https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190423/getting-pixel-values-at-single-point-using-rasterio for a start.

Comment: `IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0`

Comment: I get a negative index for a pixel! Either the code (first answer) is not working, or I am doing  something else wrong. But it is not working!

Comment: Maybe you can point me to a webpage where I can select a region and download the selected elevation data?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/190423/2856 https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/411359/2856 https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/228968/2856